# Slope of secant and tangent lines (supported by MVT)

Tags: calculus, tangent-line, slope, secant

For the function $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ on the interval $[1,8]$ find the point $(c,f(c))$ guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem, at which the slope of the tangent line is equal to the slope of the secant line over the entire interval.

(a)  Find the slope of the secant line through the endpoints of the graph on $[1, 8]$.

(b)  Find the slope of the tangent line at an arbitrary $x$-value $c$.

(c)  Set these two expressions equal to find the value of $c$ satisfying the MVT.

(d)  Write your answer as an ordered pair twice, first in exact form and then with both coordinates rounded to four decimal places.

I’m not sure if I did this properly but I got the equation for the (tangent?) line is $y= \frac{x}{7} + \frac{6}{7}$ and for part a I got the slope is $m=\frac{1}{7}$. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The equation you got is for the secant line, not the tangent line. I find it helpful to go to a graphing calculator (https://www.desmos.com/calculator) if you're doubting, and graph the expressions. You'll see that the line you have is not tangent to the graph, so you still have some work to do to find the tangent line.

Comment: How do I find the tangent line? I know I take the derivative but I’m not sure where to go from there

Comment: Remember: The derivative of a function $f$ at a point $x$ tells you the slope of the tangent line at $(x,f(x))$. We can see from your secant line that the slope is $x/7$, so try to find where the derivative is equal to $1/7$. Once that is done, you can use point-slope form to find the equation for the line.

Comment: Re-reading the question, it wants you to find the slope at an arbitrary point $c$. This is exactly the same, but just use the letter $c$ instead of $x$. Also it looks like you don't need the formula for the tangent line. You only need the point at which it is tangent.

Comment: I got it to be (c/3)^(-2/3) for the tangent line and then when I solved for c I got 3.5642. If you could confirm this that would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't look correct to me. Since it looks like you've put in effort, I'll post an answer in a bit. In the mean time, I encourage you to try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got that the secant line is $y=\frac x7 + \frac x6$. From this we can see that the slope of the secant line is $\frac17$.

So, we are asked to find the slope of the tangent line at an arbitrary value $c$. From the power rule, we get the following:
$$
\frac d{dx}x^{1/3}=\frac13x^{-2/3}.
$$
When they say to find it for an arbitrary value $c$, they just mean to use this instead:
$$
\frac13c^{-2/3}.
$$

So, that expression is the slope of the tangent line at $c$. We are looking for when the slope of the tangent line is $1/7$, so we want
$$
\begin{align}
\frac13c^{-2/3} &= \frac17\\
c^{-2/3} &= \frac37\\
c &= \left(\frac37\right)^{-3/2}
\end{align}.
$$

That's the exact form of the $c$ where the slope of the tangent line is equal to $\frac17$. That's the $x$ coordinate. To get the $y$ coordinate, just plug that into the function.
$$
\left(\left(\frac37\right)^{-3/2}\right)^{1/3}=\left(\frac37\right)^{-1/2}.
$$

And that should be it. Your ordered pair is
$$
\left(\left(\frac37\right)^{-3/2} , \left(\frac37\right)^{-1/2}\right).
$$
Now, for the rounding it to four decimal places, just put that into a calculator.

Comment: This is what I ended up getting, thanks a lot for confirming my answer!